# Best way to replace outdoor spigot

Tags: spigot

I have to replace a 50 year old backyard bib and I don't know if it screws out or if the faucet was originally soldered on the the 1/2 " tube.

What is the best way to approach this?

Below is a picture of the exterior view. The inside view is just the tube going into a wood sill board.

I haven't done any soldering in 20 years and I'm wondering if there's now an easier way of doing this project.

Should I just cut a 12" length of the existing copper supply tube and solder a new 12" assembly (faucet & soldered 12" replacement) and sliding it through the existing exterior hole and then soldering them with a copper union?

Or is there an easier way to join copper these days (ferruled compression fittings, etc.)?

[image]

Comment: Provlima, you have asked [many questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/69802/provlima?tab=questions) and have resolved none of them. Please take the [tour] and respond to your plethora of volunteer helpers with votes and accepts before posting more questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access, I would put in a new frost free (the valve seat is at the end of a rod.

[image: Frost free sillcock.]

This particular one allows you to thread it on, or solder it on.  Lowes.

If you don't have a frost problem, this is still probably the easiest way to get the connection where you can work on it.

Note:  Whenever I have to repair something, I also put in a shut off valve, figuring that if I have to repair it once, I will likely have to again.